# Spring Boot Whitelabel Error Page while adding or updating a row

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

So I'm getting a Whitelabel Error Page when I add a category,

```
http://localhost:8080/saveCat?categoryId=5&category=querty
```

And when I try to update a category,

```
http://localhost:8080/updateCat?categoryId=1&category=azerty
```

**CategoryController**

```
//Save a category
@RequestMapping(value="/saveCat", method=RequestMethod.PUT)
@ResponseBody
public Category saveCategory(Category cat){
    return categoryRepository.save(cat);
}

@RequestMapping(value="/updateCat" , method=RequestMethod.PUT)
@ResponseBody
public Category updateCategory(Category c){
    categoryRepository.saveAndFlush(c);
    return c;
}
```

For the RequestMethod I've tried both GET and PUT but no change. Any input would be appreciated.

Comment: try to find the error description in logs. Add logging to your project if you haven't done it yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem was a confusion between the **table category** and the **attribute category** of the class Category when i changed the nomination of the attribute to ***categoryN*** it works fine!

Thank you for all your answers.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The error is valid because there is no `JSP` to view. Actually what you are doing here is returning a `Category` type object and object cannot be displayed as a `view`.

Download a Chrome Extension [Postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop?hl=en) and test your `API` in it.

The first basic thing to understand is the **difference in architectures**.

One end you have the `MVC` architecture, which is based on your normal web app, using web pages, and the browser makes a request for a page:

```
Browser <---> Controller <---> Model
               |      |
               +-View-+
```

The browser makes a request, the controller (`@Controller`) gets the model (`@Entity`), and creates the view (`JSP`) from the model and the view is returned back to the client. This is the basic web app architecture.

On the other end, you have a `RESTful` architecture. In this case, there is no `View`. The Controller only sends back the model (or resource representation, in more `RESTful` terms). The client can be a JavaScript application, a Java server application, any application in which we expose our REST API to. With this architecture, the client decides what to do with this model. Take for instance Twitter. Twitter as the Web (`REST`) `API`, that allows our applications to use its API to get such things as status updates, so that we can use it to put that data in our application. That data will come in some format like `JSON` or `XML`.